# Why am I getting an "undefined label" error in java?

Tags: java, label, continue

Why am I getting an undefined label error in following code?
(I am leaving out some irrelevant code ...)

```
 loopLabel: 
 for(i=0;;i++)
 {
   { // some code;
   }
   { // some code;
   }
 }

 if(condition)
 {
     if(condition)
     { // some code
     }
     else 
     { 
           //some code;
           continue loopLabel;
     }
 }
```

Comment: you can put continue inside if which is inside that upper for loop but not in standalone if. Because its used to break a loop, meaning ignore everything else what is left in the loop end here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`continue` is used to skip to the start of a new iteration of a loop; you use a label if you have nested loops and you want to specify which one to jump to. You're trying to use it like a `goto` to jump to a totally unrelated section of code, which isn't allowed

Legal usage is something like:

```
foo:
while(cond1) {
    code;
    while(cond2) {
        if(cond3) {
            continue foo;
        }
    }
}
```

([Java guide on branching statements](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html))

Comment: then... is there any alternative where i can get exact functionality as that of goto??

Comment: Actually, you could wrap your code in a `do { ... } while (false);` to be able to jump back to the beginning. but that would lead to unclear / unmaintainable code, so it is frowned upon.

Comment: `continue` wouldn't jump back to the beginning in that case, it would test the condition (`false`) and end the loop. You would have to do `while(true) {}` and break out at the end. But yes, it would be horrible

Comment: i should probably restructure the program..!
Thakns everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Because you are outside of the loop. The label is visible only inside the loop.

Labels are used only to break and continue loops.

Comment: No idea, but I canceled it out